# Firefox fonts gets garbled?

Tags: firefox, fonts

My firefox fonts gets garbled. I don't know why? please help.

Look at the attached image !

[image: Please see bottom part of the image]

Comment: Is the language Hindi?

Comment: Yes the above image points to Hindi language. But I am getting same problem with other sites.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, with garbled fonts, and I had to change the font setting.  To change you font settings, click on the **Firefox** button, and choose **Preferences** --> **Preferences**

[image]

Once you click on **Preferences**, you will see

[image]

There you can change your font setting.  In my case I choose Times New Roman, and that fixed my issue.  Then click on **Advanced tab** to further choose your font settings, and character encoding

[image]

Hope that this will help you fix your issue.  If more help is needed don`t hesitate to ask.

Comment: No dear it didn't fixed the problem, still showing same garbled fonts.

Comment: any chance you can upload an image of it in english?

Comment: is there anyone who can help.... still with same problem on utf8 sites mostly...