# OpenOffice Menu Items, Firefox URL and Header fonts are gibberish images after Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, firefox, fonts, openoffice.org

[image]Yesterday I've upgraded Ubuntu from 18 to 20, after that my Firefox url, header, menu items all fonts have become boxes and gibberish images. Please see the screenshot attached.[image]. Can someone please help to resolve this issue?

Update: Not only Firefox, I see all the Openoffice calc or writer menu are also garbled.[image]

Comment: Which is your display language? Is the package `fonts-dejavu-core` installed?

Comment: Display language is English. When I did fc-list | grep dejavu it listed many dejavu fonts like Sans, Mono, Condensed. Not sure this is what you meant:

Comment: I asked about the package: `apt policy fonts-noto-core`

Comment: Also, what does this command output: `fc-match`

Comment: `apt policy fonts-noto-core`  
`  Installed: 20200323-1build1~ubuntu20.04.1
  Candidate: 20200323-1build1~ubuntu20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 20200323-1build1~ubuntu20.04.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20200323-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages`

Comment: `fc-match` gives : `DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"`

Comment: That looks as expected. I have no other thought offhand.

Comment: That's a Mozilla thang, try the andwer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/142844/firefox-fonts-gets-garbled

Comment: I can't even navigate to the Preferences page as you can see all my fonts there are also garbled.

Comment: Maybe some translations are missing. Try to run `gnome-language-selector` and set your language

Comment: It has nothing to do with language, all other applications are correctly showing the language except Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Still could not find the root cause of it. Only resetting to the default settings by

```
dconf reset -f /
```

brought back the fonts in Firefox and Open Office.

Comment: Based on this solution, it looks like a system font setting was changed to refer to a symbol font.